# Should I run before weight training or after weight training?

Tags: weightlifting, running, weight-loss, workout

My main goal is to lose fat. I have been struggling a bit to lose it. I want someone’s honest opinion about the topic: Should I run before weight training or after weight training? I read some article but they didn’t satisfy me with their answer. I usually run before weight training  because after a workout I feel tired. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have selected an answer the more info the better I think. I would say what would work the best and what has worked the best in the past for me is to split up my cardio and weight training days just to get the most out of my workouts. Otherwise if that is not possible and you want to train optimally when you do your main muscle building exercises then do your cardio after you workout.

If your muscles are already fatigued then I know personally it can result in a lack of good form and slow steady push or pull movements. When it comes to fat burning then as with most things to do with physical fitness diet is key.So the honest truth is if you are eating poorly then it no matter how much exercise you do it's not going to help. Perhaps try working out your daily calorie needs and then seeing if your food intake is correct.

What I do as cardio is high intensity interval training for about 20min. There's lots of programs out there that can provide you with an interval plan but just out of interest that's what I use. But I would say for fat loss which it sounds like you are focused on, focus on your diet first.

Answer (score 2):

By workout I assume you mean weight training

I would recommend running after your workout as your muscles will be tired. Your body is resorting to fat supply for energy as long as you had enough calories before your workout with the correct macros. Otherwise you may be losing muscular gains also.

Answer (score 0):

Since muscles are more stiff and less flexible after rigorous weight training, I would recommend running first if you're going to immediately switch to weight training after.  Your muscles will be more warmed up and loose without static stretching before the weight training (heavy stretching before weights is not healthy while no warm-up also raises the risk of an injury).  Be mindful of any running injuries or pain before weight training to prevent injuries as well. I've tried both routes many times and running before weights always works out most efficiently in the long-run.  I've noticed there is a high boost in running immediately after weights, but that is short lived before the reality of stiffness and added pain (and a sense of higher risk of injury) kicks in.  Perhaps a short mile after the weights is still safe, but if you're running several miles, I'd stick to knocking those out before pumping the iron.  As far as energy is concerned, running before weights surprisingly doesn't seem to take away *that much* fuel for pumping iron.

Comment: Thanks for the information, in daily base I run like 2 to 3 mile and do weight training. Somehow I am gaining lots of weight or gaining  muscle, idk. I want to loose fat on my belly and for that I also do all kind fat lose exercise. Still don’t see change a lot.

Comment: You may need to experiment with different diets such as the Ketogenic Diet along with a greater focus on cardio, soda/alcohol reduction, stress reduction, adequate sleep, and plenty of water for your body size. Weight alone is not the best measurement of body fat if you are not obese or severely low in body fat, I would focus more on the mirror and measuring tape around key the belly and other key areas to document progress.  Weight lifting and bulking up often does involve some fat gain as well, so many people explore "Cutting" that focuses more on cardio & stricter diet/intermittent fasting.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should train weights and run on different days.

Also you should do shorter: 30-45 minutes but intense runs. 
Running slow for a long time is an outdated way of loosing fat. The problem with this approach is that you only look at what happens during the workout. Yes maybe you loose say 600 calories by jogging for 1 1/2 hour. If you instead run fast for 1/2 hour you burn maybe 300 calories, but then you also burn 200 calories after the workout since the intensity of the workout has increased your metabolic rate.